How can I access custom data fetched from posts in a javascript script?
I am trying to fetch the lat, long data from custom fields in my posts in order to make a map layer with them (openlayers).

I added custom long and lat fields to each post
I created a function to fetch this data
I enqueued scripts in my functions.php

I want to access this data in another script (travel-map.js) but window.mapData remains not available. How can I make this data accessible in my Javascript script?
Thank you
functions.php
function enqueue_fetch_data_from_posts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fetch-data-from-posts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/fetch-data-from-posts.js', array('openlayers'), '1.0', true );
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_fetch_data_from_posts' );

  //Query data from all the posts
  function map_data() {
    $args = array(
      'meta_key' => 'latitude',
      'meta_value' => '', // We only need posts with a value
      'meta_compare' => '!='
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
  
    $markers = array();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
      $lat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'latitude', true);
      $lng = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'longitude', true);
      if (is_numeric($lat) && is_numeric($lng)) {
        $markers[] = array(
          'lat' => $lat,
          'lng' => $lng,
          'link' => get_permalink($post->ID), // Link to the blog post
          'title' => $post->post_title // Optional: Title for tooltip
        );
      echo '<script>console.log("Marker Data:", ' . json_encode($markers) . ');</script>';
      }
    }
  
    wp_localize_script('travel-map-script', 'mapData', $markers);
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'map_data' );


  function enqueue_travel_map_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'travel-map-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/travel-map.js', array('openlayers'), '1.0', true );
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_travel_map_script' );

travel-map.js
  // Create markers for blog posts
  var markers = [];

  console.log("window.mapData:", window.mapData); // Check the value here

  if (window.mapData && window.mapData.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < window.mapData.length; i++) {
      var marker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([window.mapData[i].lng, window.mapData[i].lat])),
      });
      marker.set('title', window.mapData[i].title); // Optional: Set title for tooltip
      marker.set('link', window.mapData[i].link);
      });
    }
  } else {
    console.warn("window.mapData is not available or empty. Skipping marker creation.");
  }


The best practice way would be to create a REST API endpoint using register_rest_route() hooked to rest_api_init that your Javascript can query.

Thanks, that works, but I would still like to know why the first didn't function
